# PHP glob() does not list file size

Tags: php

I have a PHP file that lists the contents of a directory. For some unknown reason it will not list the file size. Please look at this code and tell me what I am doing wrong. It does list the file name.

```
<?php // Build file list for delete
$x=1;
foreach (glob("../main_page_images/*.*") as $filename) {
$filename = substr($filename, 20);
if($y==1){
echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#CCFFCC\"><td>".$x.".</td><td><span id=".$filename.">".$filename."    </span></td><td>".filesize($filename)."</td><td></td><td></td><td><div class=\"prayer\"   id=".$filename."><span class=\"count\"></span>&nbsp;<br><button class=\"count\">Delete</button></div></td></tr>\n";
$y=0;}
else{
$y=1;
echo "<tr ><td>".$x.".</td><td><span id=".$filename.">".$filename."</span></td><td>".filesize($filename)."</td><td></td><td></td><td><div class=\"prayer\" id=".$filename."><span class=\"count\"></span>&nbsp;<br><button class=\"count\">Delete</button></div></td></tr>\n";}
$x++;
}
?>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Because you `substr($filename, 20)`, so when you try `filesize($filename)` became a problem(because you need no set real name, but not a substr)

So make something like this:

```
$filenameShirt = substr($filename, 20);
```

And use `$filenameShirt` to get file name and `$filename` to get file zsize

Comment: Never thought of that... Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there any other information you can get from glob()? For example file creation date? Thanks!

Comment: using glob() you can get only array containing the matched files/directories, an empty array if no file matched or FALSE on error